# Python Scrolling Game Syntax Error

Tags: python, syntax

I'm new to programming and I'm creating a scrolling game in which the player must avoid red blocks and collect green blocks.

I am able to get the blocks to appear on the screen at random positions, and I can get the player block moving left and right, but I'm having trouble getting the blocks to actually scroll down the page. I'm not sure how to do it and I'm getting a syntax error when I try.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
for k in range(0, MAX_BLOCKS(10):
    move(0, scrolling_blocks[k].getScrollSpeed())

    # Slow down movement
    time.sleep(0.03)
```

This gives me a syntax error on the `time.sleep(0.3)` line.

This is the algorithm we're supposed to follow:

```
for k in range 0 to MAX_BLOCKS(10) 
 move scrolling_blocks[k] by its own scroll speed (in the Y direction) using method move
```

I'm really confused and I also don't understand how to make it move in the Y direction or what that even means.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a closing parenthesis:

```
for k in range(0, MAX_BLOCKS(10):
#                           ^--^
#      opened ^--      close? --^
```

Because Python is still looking for the rest of that expression, the exception only is thrown on a later line.